# Multiple git repos in plesk virtual hosts

Tags: git

Each plesk vhost only has one user access that httpdocs directory. I want to manage a whole bunch of separate virtual hosts using Git.

Does this mean installing a separate Git repository with a separate user / ssh public key combination for each virtual host or is there a way of centralising it at all?

[Gitosis](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis) sounds like it might help - but I'm not sure if it gets round pushing the files to each virtual host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are usually 2 ways to manage this sort of problem ;

1. You have a bare repository centralizing your application somewhere on the server, and one clone of this repository (with a working tree) in each `httpdocs` folder

   you then set a `post-receive hook` on the bare repo to update all `httpdocs` clones of this repository, usually a shell script will suffice (and can setup permissions and do global `chmod`based on your users)

   And you have another copy of the repository on a local machine which pushes to this `bare`repository on the server, which triggers the post-receive hooks, and updates all the "children" repositories in your `httpdocs`directories
2. You get the `.git`part out of `httpdocs` (which I would recommand) and setup repositories in the `/private/home/git/myrepo` (create it) folder with a `working tree` in `httpdocs`

   ```
   $ git --git-dir=/var/www/vhosts/newdomain.tld/private/home/git/newdomain.tld \
   --work-tree=/var/www/vhosts/newdomain.tld/httpdocs   init  &&  \
   echo "gitdir: /var/www/vhosts/newdomain.tld/private/home/git/newdomain.tld" \
   > /var/www/vhosts/newdomain.tld/httpdocs/.git
   ```

   this way, your `httpdocs` remains relatively clean of versioning info (except for the `.git`**FILE** (not dir) created in `/var/www/vhosts/newdomain.tld/httpdocs/`, which is just a GIT way of symlinking the `working tree` with the location of the `GITDIR`)

   the rest of the procedure is the same : bare repository, post-receive hooks

I personally gave up on Gitosis, gitolite & palls, because it's too much overhead for just a few repositories. Properly setting up your remote branches and a shell script is all that's needed (launched by the post-receive hook)

More on `hook`on the [githooks(5)](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) manpage